# Batch processing a MongoDB Collection using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loops, mongoose, batch-processing

There is a way to iterate over a MongoDB Collection using Mongoose library in batch?

For example, my collection has 50 documents. Batch size is set to: 5. So the iteration will be composed of 10 loops, at the firs loop I get first 5 docs i.e. 0...5, at second loop I get 5...10 and so on until 50.

At the end of the loop it should be done 5 HTTP calls to MongoDB server in total.

How I can do that I Mongoose?